# Delete rows with same columns data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am having a temp table with the following data:

```
tbl_t
id   name_id     date      t1    t2    s1    s2
 1      25     10/05/20   same  same  NULL  NULL
 2      23     11/05/21   same  same  home  NULL
 3      25     12/05/20   same  NULL  NULL  NULL
 4      25     13/06/20   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
```

Desire output:

```
tbl_t
id   name_id     date      t1    t2    s1    s2
 2      23     11/05/21   same  same  home  NULL
 3      25     12/05/20   same  NULL  NULL  NULL
```

I want to delete all rows where t1=t2 and s1=s1

I tried the following sql but i noticed that it is not working.

`DELETE FROM tbl_t WHERE t1=t2 AND s1=s2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the `NULL` values.  Use the `NULL`-safe comparison operator:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_t
    WHERE t1 <=> t2 AND s1 <=> s2;
```

Almost any comparison with `NULL` results in `NULL` -- including `NULL = NULL`.  And `NULL` values are treated as `false` in a `WHERE` clause (or equivalently `WHERE` clauses only keep rows where the condition evaluates unequivocally to `true`).

Comment: `NULL` was my problem. And testing different solutions but with no luck. It was so simple.